# Issue initializing a signal in a process at program start up VHDL

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, test-bench

I have a input signal (Data) which is std_logic_vector (511 downto 0). I assign the first 256 bits to a signal ch1_sample_block, and the second 256 bits to a signal ch2_sample_block. I use concurrent assignment in my architecture body so that whatever value Data has at start up, these two child signals also have this value. I have created a process vector_assignment after this that allocates (in 16-bit std_logic_vector chunks) all of the data in each child signal to two arrays, ch1_vector_block and ch2_vector_block, which are each 0 to 15 of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0).

The problem: I would like these array signals ch1_vector_block and ch2_vector_block to be initialized to the data contained in ch1_sample_block and ch2_sample_block. The issue is that because they are assigned in the process (which doesn't get "woken" up until a change on clk or Data), they are initialized to "U" (uninitialized). The reason I didn't initialize the ch1_vector_block/ch2_vector_blocks is because I didn't want to initialize 32 vectors. That's the whole point of the process

I assign a value to Data (the input signal) at time t = 0, and because ch1_sample_block and ch2_sample_block are concurrently assigned Data, their values at t = 0 are initialized how I want them to be.

But how come at time t = 0, even though the value of Data changes, the process doesn't wake up and assign values to the vector blocks? How do I need to implement this instead? I'm trying to avoid doing this:

ch1_vector_block(0) <= ch1_sample_block(15 downto 0)
.
.
.
ch1_vector_block(15) <= ch1_sample_block(255 downto 240)

Thanks!

[Modelsim simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFMx2.png)

[Updated](http://textuploader.com/dme78)

[Updated Source Code](http://textuploader.com/dme7c)

Comment: Your don't provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Include any code necessary in the question itself, Successful questions and answers are a search resource. Your problem can't be replicated. `Clk` is in the process sensitivity list but not used. `Data` is in the sensittvity list while you use `ch1_sample_block` and `ch2_sample_block` which would have events in the following simulation cycle and not valid until then. Correct the sensitivity list.  *they are initialized to "unsigned"* Do you mean they are Uninitialized (all 'U's)?

Comment: Adding a testbench for the code not shown in your question that replicates the shown inputs, changing the process sensitivity list to `process (ch1_sample_block, ch2_sample_block)` (neither `Clk` nor `Data` are used in the process) gives the [correct waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Wbp.png). Note that if you want DataProc updated on a clock edge you should infer an RTL register.

Comment: All processes in VHDL run at time 0. Therefore, any process that is "woken up" by some change on `clk` or `Data` will have already run once before (at time 0). You need to provide an _MCVE_.

Comment: Hi @user1155120, sorry second post on this website ever so I'm still learning good practice/conventions. I updated the Modelsim screen shot and added the testbench code. I did mean to say 'unitialized' instead of 'unsigned'. I updated the sensitivity list so now it is sensitive to ch1_sample_block/ch2_sample_block. I thought that it wouldn't have made a difference though since these two signals are concurrently assigned Data in the architecture. Is this not true? Also why is DataProc still not updated until one cycle later? I'd like this updated at power up

Thanks again

Comment: I figured out why DataProc wasn't updating. Ch1_vector_block is a signal (which DataProc's assignment depends on). Because it is a signal, it doesn't update immediately inside the process. I was essentially using it as though it was a variable that would be updated immediately. To fix this, I just created a new process which was sensitive to ch1_vector_block/ch2_vector_block and did the DataProc assignment in a for loop there.